# TextViews animate only once on Android 4

Tags: android, animation, textview, backwards-compatibility, layout-animation

I have a layout (RelativeLayout) with a number of buttons and two text views. For each change of information I fade out all the views, update the information and then fade in the views. I use layoutanimations for this.

The very strange thing is that the text views can only be animated once. They fade in and  out correctly one time and then won't get animated anymore. The buttons, on the other hand, continue to animate just fine.

Another perhaps strange thing is that I don't get this problem on android 2.3.x but on android 4.0.x.

I can work around the problem by clearing animations on the text views after fade in, but it doesn't look so nice since they still don't get faded in.

I have tried to clear animations on the text views before fade in but it doesn't help. I have also tried different settings of the targetSdkVersion property in the manifest, but without any results.

The fade in animation (fade out is similar):

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="750" 
    android:fillAfter="true" 
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" 
/>
```

The animation code (this is run everytime the layout is to fade in):

```
// Set listener.
viewGroup.setLayoutAnimationListener(listener);

// Load animation.
final Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);

// Create and start animation controller.
final LayoutAnimationController animController = new LayoutAnimationController(fadeIn);
viewGroup.setLayoutAnimation(animController);
animController.setAnimation(fadeIn);
animController.setDelay(FADE_IN_DELAY + extraDelay);
animController.setOrder(LayoutAnimationController.ORDER_REVERSE);
animController.start();
```

Does anyone have any idea? Is there some kind of animation specific difference between Buttons and TextViews? Are there any animation changes in Android 4 that breaks the backward compatibility?

Thank you!

Comment: My fade in animation is working correctly again in 4.2.1. I won't spend any more time on trying to fix this on 4.0.x since I got a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Layout animations occur only when a view group lays out it's children - as per the `[LayoutAnimationController][1]` docs the same animation is played for each child, but with a different starting time - it's generally used for e.g. a `ListView` or `GridView` to animate the entrance of the items.

The animation will **not** generally be played when you update your content. You'll need to use `View.startAnimation(Animation)` and `View.clearAnimation()` to ensure your animations are played each time you update your content.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The layout that I animate is viewGroup in my code snippet above, and the layout animation is started with the last line: animController.start();

Comment: I may add that I don't attach the layout animation in the layout xml. It's handled in the java code, as the snippet describes.